# boto3 getting tags from workspace instances

Tags: boto3, amazon-workspaces

I am writing a lambda job that will perform various tasks with workspaces. However I am having difficulty collecting the Workspace Tag I would like to trigger on. Currently my code looks like this:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    DirectoryId = 'd-#####'
    wsclient = boto3.client('workspaces')
    wsresponce = wsclient.describe_workspaces(DirectoryId='d-90672fcb89')['Workspaces']

    for eachws in wsresponce:
        print(eachws['WorkspaceId'])
        wstag=wsclient.describe_tags(ResourceId=eachws['WorkspaceId'])
        print(wstag)
        for eachwstag in wstag:
            print(eachwstag)
```

Looking at the results of `wstag` I can see the information I want, example below. However I haven't been able to find a way to get the Value associated with the key in place for this work. I assumed `eachwstag` was also a "dict" perhaps this is incorrect(?).
I assume there maybe another way to handle the json output to find the value I need.

```
{'TagList': [{'Key': 'key1', 'Value': 'value1'}, {'Key': 'key2needed', 'Value': 'value2'}], 'ResponseMetadata': {...}}
```

Comment: `wstag` is a dictionary with `TagList` key and value is a list of dictionaries each of which has a `Key` and `Value` key.  So to get each tag key and value you need to iterate over `wstag['TagList']`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @wstag for your comment. The closing `['TagList']` was what I was missing. Completed loop was:

```
        wstag=wsclient.describe_tags(ResourceId=eachws['WorkspaceId'])['TagList']
        for eachwstag in wstag:
            grouptag = 0
            if eachwstag['Key'] == 'Group':
                grouptag = 1
                if eachwstag['Value'] in groupA:
                    print(eachwstag['Value'] + "I'm in groupA")
                else:
                    print(eachwstag['Value'] + "I'm not in this gorup")
        if grouptag == 0:
            print "I need a group tag"
```

Thank you agian.